# Normal and Inverse Normal of Non-negative sets

Tags: statistics

I work as a math tutor at a community college, and a conceptual question stumped me in statistics:

In intro statistics, students are taught how to take X values and normalize them to Z values via $\mu$ and and $\sigma$. Once normalized, you can take a table and figure out the Z value at the P percentile, then use:

$x = z \sigma + \mu$

to "unnormalize" the number. The question is: if I have X values for a non-negative set (weight or height) and use this method, the normal CDF calculates the Z value for the P percentile over all reals. If I take that Z value and unnormalize it back to X, do I need to account for the fact that some Z values don't map back to X? If so, do I have to adjust my value to compensate?

Phrased another way: my X values are on the set $[0, \infty)$ and when I normalize them, the Z values are on $(-\infty, \infty)$. When I map an X value to Z, the CDF area gives me the probability of that Z value (and the corresponding X). However, normalizing $x = 0$ yields a finite $z$ value; there are no X values less than $x = 0$ but there are $z$ values that exist to the left of that. So if the area behind a Z value for a positive, non-zero X value is found, doesn't the area include contributions from X values that don't exist?

It seems like the map from X to Z isn't bijective, so the question almost doesn't make sense, and yet it's used in statistics (at least undergrad statistics) all the time. I don't know of any other context where a purely injective function is treated as invertible for the sake of applicability.

I understand that the contribution of Z values that map to negative X values will be small, but as a theoretical exercise I was curious to know if we just ignore the contribution of those Z values or if there's some higher-level math magic going on in the background.

Also, does this question change when I encounter different sets of X? (i.e. $x \in (0,\infty)$ etc.) I could feasibly imagine an equation that "squishes" the Z values that approach $-\infty$ onto the part of X near $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform a Z-test, you are assuming your statistic (what you call an x-value) comes from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. In particular, you are assuming your statistic could have been any real number.

Of course in certain situations, this is not true (e.g., measuring height or weight), which strictly speaking should mean you cannot use the Z-test. However, the normal distribution is often a close approximation despite these issues. Saying that the distribution of adult heights follows a normal distribution may not make sense because you might get negative heights, but the probability of that occurring is tiny ($<1\%$), and the normal distribution is close enough to the real distribution of heights that some people feel comfortable with using the approximation. (["All models are wrong, but some are useful."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong))

Of course, in some situations, the normal distribution is a poor approximation, or maybe you are in a situation where it is absolutely impermissible to consider a distribution that gives nonzero probability to "impossible" values. Then you should consider other models, or do some truncation. Someone more knowledgeable than I might give a better answer.

Comment: That was about my line of thinking. My coworkers and I kind of landed on it being part of the modelling and that "exactness" is somewhat irrelevant with regards to modelling data via distributions. Models are always going to have inaccuracies, and if a non-zero positive data set is grouped tightly around a non-zero positive average you won't get much error introduced. The idea framed in a theoretical context just lodged at the back of my mind and gave me that nerd itch for an answer.